# Product Addons for WooCommerce conditional logic working on product page but not on quick view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I am a beginner developer of WordPress and developing a food store for a client. I have used the following plugins

1. Product table lite for woocommerce
2. Advanced Product Fields (Product Addons) for WooCommerce.
3. Woo Quick view

The main issue I am facing is that the conditional logic is working fine on the product page but not working on the quick view of the product, I have used "add to cart via ajax".

The images attached may describe my problem more...

[Conditional logic working on product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4WK5.png)

[Conditional logic not working on quick view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbj18.png)

This may be a solution to my problem, got it from internet but don't know how to load scripts of product page on mainpage
"Load all custom plugins scripts(for datepicker,colorpicker,SumoSelect) in all pages: By default custom scripts will be loading in the product page only. But if you want to use custom fields in quick view pop ups, it needs to load scripts in all pages."

Comment: First you need to check quick view code and you need to add the conditional logic for the same.

if you have used the plugin for quick view then you need to check plugin author provide any filter and action for the same then you add the conditional logic for the same.

Comment: there's no filter or any action in the plugin, extra options are working fine in the quick view but conditional logic options do not work

Answer (score 0):

The plugin needs a specific integration with the quick view plugin you use. Since all quick view plugins work differently, there's usually not a "one case fits all" solution.

Luckily, the premium version works with a few quick view plugins out of the box. You can see here [which plugins are compatible with Advanced Product Fields](https://www.studiowombat.com/knowledge-base/which-plugins-and-themes-are-compatible-with-advanced-product-fields-for-woocommerce/).